# how to protect files in directory?

Tags: .htaccess, directory

I am creating a website for one of my client. consider this is my website: www.website.com

I saved my all my files in sub-domain like-> http://sub.website.com/file.jpg

I also have robots.txt file in sub-domain like-> http://sub.website.com/robots.txt.

If someone directly enter this url "http://sub.website.com/robots.txt", They can able to read my robots.txt file.

What should i do, if i want protect that files?

Comment: All robots must be able to read this file. You should not protect the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your robots.txt file "un-readable" than search engines won't be able to view it to know what not to index.